# are strings different after toCharArray and then used by String.copyValueOf

Tags: java, string

in Java is it exactly the same for a String been transferred to char array and then changed back?
i.e.

```
String a = "Hello World";
String b = String.copyValueOf(a.toCharArray());
```

are String a and b guaranteed to be the same?

Yes I know in this situation they would be equal, but I mean, are they guaranteed to be equal in any case no matter what was the value?

Comment: http://ideone.com/yy3FCU

Comment: You can run the code and get your answer, no need to post a question here.

Answer (score 3):

They are going to be equal, not the same.

That is: both variables will contain the address of different String objects. But a comparison of the objects referenced by both variables using the String.equals() method will return true.